# Compare Tables column_name with views column_names

Tags: sql, sql-server

Aim is to compare tables column_name with the views columns_name to check if they have the same columns , however, getting them with different orders. Wanted to see them both with same order

```
select t1.COLUMN_NAME, t2.COLUMN_NAME from 

(select * from information_schema.columns where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dmt' and  table_name = '@tablename' ) as t1
left join
(select * from information_schema.columns where TABLE_SCHEMA  =  'models' and table_name = 'viewName') as t2
on t1.ORDINAL_POSITION = t2.ORDINAL_POSITION
```

I want get the output like in the same order, for example:

```
Column_Name 1 Column_Name 2 

    cat            cat  
    dog            dog
```

Comment: So what's wrong with what you have?

Comment: I am getting the output with different order, does not match, it comes like 
 `Column_name 1   Column_Name 2                                                                    
  cat                       dog`

Comment: That *implies*n the order of the columns is different in the objects then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to get the comparison of the columns.

```
WITH ColumnsCTE (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME) AS
(
  SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dmt' AND TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'models' AND TABLE_NAME = 'ViewName'
)

-- get the different columns of the tables / views.
SELECT t1.TABLE_NAME, t1.COLUMN_NAME AS [COLUMN_NAME 1], ISNULL(t2.COLUMN_NAME, 'missing on other table / view') AS [COLUMN_NAME 2]
FROM ColumnsCTE AS t1 LEFT JOIN ColumnsCTE AS t2 ON t1.COLUMN_NAME = t2.COLUMN_NAME AND t1.TABLE_NAME <> t2.TABLE_NAME
WHERE t2.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1a49ea657b88a0c448afe630d3f2b76f)

You can't use the `ORDINAL_POSITION` to get the expected result since the order of the columns can be different. See the following example where the `ORDINAL_POSITION` is different but the columns are available in both tables / views:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE VIEW ViewTest AS
  SELECT name, id FROM Test;
```

Comment: @KananMehdizade Please upvote his answer and mark it as answer (check the checkmark on the left of his answer). You should have enough score by now.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the attributes is identitcal (you can hardcode which attributes to select and in which order)
i strongly recommend 
"intersect" or "except" command 
increddibly strong function offering almost anything you could wish for here.

Comment: edit: this can be done on the shema/meta data too ofc